# Bash case in sequence of numbers

Tags: bash, sequence, case

```
num=0.5

avg=`seq 0.47 0.01 0.79`

case $num in
"$avg" )
echo "ok"
;;
1 )
echo "no"
;;
esac
```

Im trying to do this, if you understand. 
So, im giving it a number, and it is ok if number matches sequence.
But this does not work. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Note that `0.5` will never match the output from `seq 0.47 0.01 0.79`, but `0.50` will.

Answer (score 1):

```
num=0.5
result="not ok"
for vers in $(seq 0.47 0.01 0.79)
do
    if [ "$vers" = "$num" ] ; then
        result=ok
        break      # thanks @GreenMatt
    fi
done
echo $result
```

Comment: rule: Did you test this? I just cut and pasted the code and I get "not ok".

Comment: Yes. An input of `0.5` should give you "not ok". An input of `0.50` will be "ok".